# How can I convert SQL Stored Procedure tables to HTML using C#

Tags: c#, sql, xslt, stored-procedures

I have a large stored procedure that returns 5 different tables.
I need to display these tables generated by the stored procedures as HTML.

**As I am struggling to find what the problem is due to the seemingly meaningless error messages given by the method in the closed class; I am looking for a new solution to the problem, however all contributions are welcome**

I have inherited a system that uses a very old method for doing this through IES.Core.ReportTool.
I have an XLST file and some c# to do this -

```
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBConnStr"];

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Proc_cisiv_ProgramDayData";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProgramDayNodeID", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int);

        PageInfo pInfo = CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentContext.CurrentPageInfo;
        cmd.Parameters["@ProgramDayNodeID"].Value = pInfo.NodeID;
        cmd.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = CMS.Membership.MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser.UserID;
        ReportTool rt = new ReportTool();

        try
        {
            lit.Text = rt.GenerateHTML(Server.MapPath("~/CMSPages/XSLT/ProgrammeDay.xslt"), connStr, cmd, false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lit.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
```

but something is not quite right and it is throwing a Null Reference Exception which is as follows -

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at IES.Core.ReportTool.BaseGenerateHTMLFromSQL(String xslPathAndFileName, String xsdPathAndFileName, String xmlMapPathAndFileName, XsltArgumentList xslArgs, String DBConnStr, SqlCommand sqlCommandObject, Boolean debug) at IES.Core.ReportTool.GenerateHTML(String xslPathAndFileName, String DBconnStr, SqlCommand sqlCommandObject, Boolean debug) at ProgramDayDetail.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Projects\brsweb\CMSWebParts\MyWebPart\ProgramDayDetail.ascx.cs:line 37

Line 37 is

```
lit.Text = rt.GenerateHTML(Server.MapPath("~/CMSPages/XSLT/ProgrammeDay.xslt"), connStr, cmd, false);
```

**The solution that I have found so far (Not quite finished but it is displaying the data that is returned from the stored procedure as it should)**

```
     string connStr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBConnStr"];

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Proc_cisiv_ProgramDayData";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProgramDayNodeID", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int);

        PageInfo pInfo = CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentContext.CurrentPageInfo;

        cmd.Parameters["@ProgramDayNodeID"].Value = pInfo.NodeID;
        cmd.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = CMS.Membership.MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser.UserID;

        string mapPath = "";
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            lit.Text = ds.GetXml();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lit.Text = ex.ToString() + "</br></br>" + pInfo.NodeID + "</br></br>" + CMS.Membership.MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser.UserID + "</br></br>" + mapPath;
        }

    connection.Close();
```

Comment: So which of the locals on line 37 is null? (Use your debugger.)

Comment: I have debugged locally and connStr and cmd are both allocated. There aren't any null locals as far as I can see.

Comment: Is the the mapping to the XSLT null? `Server.MapPath("~/CMSPages/XSLT/ProgrammeDay.xslt")` In other words, try pulling out the mapping to a local variable and see if the value is null or not.

Comment: Is the XSLT file really called "ProgrammeDay.xslt" and really to be found at that location?

Comment: Good idea! But no I just tried that and it is returning the correct path of the XSLT file

Comment: Could the null reference be referring to the data that is being returned from the procedure? It seem the IES.Core.ReportTool class isn't very good at giving good error messages which is what I believe the problem is. This is why i'm looking for an alternative method to solve the problem in hope of finding a more meaningful error message.

Comment: From you description it appears you have a tool that converts the result of the SProc into XML, and then applies an XSLT to that to get the output. Replacing this would either require a re-implementation of the db result to XML conversion or of the whole process. Neither is likely to be simple. You'll probably do better working out where the tool came from and seeing if you can get some help from that direction (if you have the source in your solution, then build it for debug…).

Answer (score 0):

looking at your exception I think that the code you are showing us isn't sufficient to understand the problem. 
The call to `GenerateHTML` method starts in the right way. Inside that call you call `IES.Core.ReportTool.BaseGenerateHTMLFromSQL` and there you are getting the `System.NullReferenceException`.

The exception is  propagated until `line 37` but isn't the right line number. 

Check for inner exceptions

Comment: GenerateHTML is a closed method in the ReportTool class so I have provided you with all the code I can

Comment: So there is an error in ReportTool class. Maybe it is caused by a wrong parameter in input but the error is happening there!